# Select all the elements within an element having an attribute set to a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the followings defined :

```
var excludedFiltersPanel = $("#excludedFiltersPanel");
var includedfiltersPanel = $("#includedfiltersPanel");
```

where *Panel is just a div.

in `excludedFiltersPanel` there are some div's with attribute `data-iscorefilter="true"` e.g. :

```
<div id="filterPanel-LastName" class="filterPanel" data-iscorefilter="true">
  <Some Stuff here!>
</div>
```

I am trying to get them and move them to includedfiltersPanel:

It seems neither of these is a correct syntax:

- `excludedFiltersPanel.('[data-iscorefilter="true"]')`
- `excludedFiltersPanel.$('[data-iscorefilter="true"]')`

1.What is the correct syntax?

2.How do I append them to `includedfiltersPanel`? (I know how to append a single item, but not sure what is the common good practice here, e.g. using for loop or some JQuery magic)

Comment: `excludedFiltersPanel.find('[data-iscorefilter="true"]')` try this

Comment: notice you have to use `.attr('data-iscorefilter')` to have set the value, not `.data('iscorefilter')`

Comment: @Cine : The attributes are rendered in a php'esque style using aps.net MVC, not using Jquery to set the data- attributes, but thanks for the info.

Comment: @guradio : yep that did the trick

Comment: @Arjang glad it works i will add it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `excludedFiltersPanel there are some div's with attribute data-iscorefilter="true"`

Use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

It would look like :

`excludedFiltersPanel.find('[data-iscorefilter="true"]')`